# Ssrs 2008 dynamic columns returned by procedure

Tags: ssrs-2008

In ssrs what if there is uncertain number of columns returned by store procedure , say if i `have dates as column name`s which can very as per selection criteria of the report,eg columns can be like    `name,[2013-05-03],[2013-05-04],[2013-05-05], so on etc`.
how can i show these columns in report.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS runs queries with the FMTONLY option on to populate the list of columns. In other words, it doesn't play nice with dynamic columns because they are non-deterministic. This really comes down to a design issue with the data. One solution to look into would be to have another procedure that pivots those columns into a row. That would allow you to pass the data to the report for processing. If there are other obstacles preventing you from converting the data, that would be another good question to post along with more details.